# Adynamic access to view properties in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, stack-overflow, dry, kotlin-android-extensions

I need in my android app, to avoid having to repeat a line every time a new case appears, I wanted to do call this line in a forEach loop.

I'm in a Fragment, so my `view` refers to the current view, in which I can access not dynamically to my properties.

Here is what I did:

```kt
val product = arguments!!.getParcelable<Product>(ARG_PRODUCT)!!
listOf("fat", "fat_acids", "salt", "sugar").forEach {
    view.get<TextView>(it).text = view.context.getString(
        resources.getIdentifier("of_${it}", "string", view.context.packageName),
        product.nutriFacts[it].quantityFor100,
        product.nutriFacts[it].unit
    )
}
```

Then Android studio told me I had to make a new property accessor, in this case an operator:

```kt
private operator fun <T> View.get(property: String): T {
    return this[property]
}
```

But now the error is a StackOverflow error (ironic isn't it) at this precise line:

```kt
return this[property]
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: What relationship does `fat_acids` have to `view`? Are you trying to say that `view` has a child widget that has a widget ID of `R.id.fat_acids`?

Comment: What I mean is that `view["fat_acids"]` should refer to `view.fat_acids`, but I guess it is also its `id`.

Comment: Short of reflection, I don't know of a way to have `view["somestring"]` return the value of a `somestring` property. If we ignore that and focus on the widget ID scenario, I would use `mapOf(R.id.fat to R.string.of_fat, R.id.fat_acids to R.string.of_fat_acids, ...)`, use `findViewById()` to get the widget, and get rid of the slow `getIdentifier()` call.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out the way you asked me this questions about the ID scenario. But now the same problem occurs on the class I am trying to access the property dynamically, I guess I really do need to make the map in this case ?

Comment: If you are referring to `product.nutriFacts`, either that needs to be a `Map`, or some other object type that has a `get(String)` function, or you need to implement a function on `product` that can return a fact given some identifier. And you would need your key to be part of your loop. All of this may be premature optimization, unless you are going down this path to learn certain things in Kotlin. Maintaining your loop may be more difficult than just copying the necessary line to add a new fact.

Comment: If you have an exemple of this, I'd love to see. in my NutritionFacts, I actually have 15 different properties, and making a map of this wouldn't make sense to me, I should undo what I did and stay with my first solution. This project is also a way for me to learn Kotlin indeed, and I come from web languages, even typed like Typescript in which doing this thing is possible, that's why I am a little bit confused.

Comment: "If you have an exemple of this, I'd love to see" -- an example of what? "even typed like Typescript in which doing this thing is possible" -- that is because Typescript only ever gets transpiled into JavaScript, where `.property` and `[property]` are both available and equivalent. That is not how many (most?) other programming languages work.